# Conditionally counting distinct number of items in one column based on other columns and rows

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R, so apologies if this is way off base. But I have a dataset which looks something like this:

```
#simplified input - actual data has ~20K observations, 
#V1 is a categorical variable with 2 options, V3 is a categorical variable with 23 options

df <- tribble(
      ~V1, ~V2, ~V3,
      "A", "a", "Z",
      "A", "a", "Y",
      "A", "b", "X",
      "A", "b", "Z",
      "B", "c", "Z",
      "B", "a", "Z",
      "B", "a", "Y",
      "A", "d", "X",
      "A", "e", "X",
      "A", "f", "X",
      "A", "g", "X",
      "B", "g", "X",
      "B", "h", "X",
      "A", "i", "X",
    )
```

And I'm trying to count the distinct values of V2 based on a combination of V1 and V3. In this sample data, "a" can be found in A and B, and can be classified as Z or Y. So the output I'm envisioning would look something like, where the numbers are the distinct count of V2:

The desired output:

```
df <- tribble(
      ~V1, ~Z, ~Y, ~X,
      "A_only", 1, 0, 5,
      "B_only", 1, 0, 1,
      "Both_A_and_B", 1, 1, 1
    )
```

I'm honestly at a complete lost on how to do this, so any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question (especially 'A only', 'B only' etc), but would this work? `x %>% group_by(V1, V3) %>% distinct(V2) %>% count()`

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably not explaining my question very well. Unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't quite get me to what I need. But let's say for V1, A and B are two lists of people's names. V2 represents the names in the list, of which a, b, c are part if. Then V3 are other factors that describe those names like "Popular Male Name", "Popular Female Name", "Popular Dog Name." Some names can be described by a combination of these (and not just one). What I would be trying to figure out is how many names, organized by those descriptive factors, are on one of the lists only or both of the lists.

Comment: @akrun Apologies, added the expected solution

Comment: @for-alfie please apply it on your original data set and see how it turns out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

The problem Solved!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(V1, V2, V3) %>%
  add_count() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = V3, values_from = n) %>%
  group_by(V2) %>%
  mutate(V1 = ifelse(length(V2) > 1, "Both_A_and_B", 
                     ifelse(length(V2) == 1 & V1 == "A", "A_only", 
                            "B_only"))) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise(across(Z:X, ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))


# A tibble: 3 x 4
  V1               Z     Y     X
  <chr>        <int> <int> <int>
1 A_only           1     0     5
2 B_only           1     0     1
3 Both_A_and_B     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is getting very close to what I need! When I apply it to my much larger dataset with many values of V2, it's able to say for each V2 whether it is A only, B only, or Both A and B, but then there are many rows of values. Seems like there needs to be a step where you add up the count in each column grouped on V1?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, this was the best I could do with your sample data. Could you please show me how the problem might occur?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR perhaps this may also work `df %>% group_by(V2, V3) %>% summarise(V1 = str_c(unique(V1), collapse = "_and_"), .groups = 'drop') %>% mutate(V2 = 1) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = V3, values_from = V2, values_fill = 0 )`

Comment: It works to the perfection. @for-alfie please check the solution posted by dear akrun, I believe this is the best solution.

Comment: My fault for not providing in the last response! So let's say the starting data is longer now with more possible values for V2.

`example <- tribble(
  ~V1, ~V2, ~V3,
  "A", "a", "Z",
  "A", "a", "Y",
  "A", "b", "X",
  "A", "b", "Z",
  "B", "c", "Z",
  "B", "a", "Z",
  "B", "a", "Y",
  "A", "d", "X",
  "A", "e", "X",
  "A", "f", "X",
  "A", "g", "X",
  "B", "g", "X",
  "B", "h", "X",
  "A", "i", "X",
)` 

With your solution it ends up showing multiple rows. @AnoushiravanR

Comment: No just try the solution posted by dear @akrun .

Comment: No it's ok I got it, let's see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks @AnoushiravanR ! I provided an edit to my original post with what I see with both of your solutions on the larger data set. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: @for-alfie I made an edit to my post. Check it out please, I hope this works, however I am not sure.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Thanks! From some reason this one isn't giving what I would expect for "Both_A_and_B." But I think if you add a distinct() after your mutate it works?

Comment: @for-alfie I added a `distinct()` function and edited my code for the third time. It leads to your desired output.

Comment: Or a slight variation of Anoushiravan's solution `df %>% group_by(V2, V3) %>% mutate(V1 = case_when(n_distinct(V1) == 2 ~ 'A and B', TRUE ~ V1)) %>% ungroup %>% distinct(V3, V2, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% count(V1, V3) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = V3, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)`

Comment: @akrun It's fantasatic. I think you should post it.

Comment: It is almost like your solution and doesn't add any value

Comment: Thanks @AnoushiravanR. It worked perfectly! Akrun I'll try your solution in a bit to learn more.

Comment: @for-alfie , My pleasure, glad to be of any help. akrun 's solution is way better than mine, he is just too humble to admit it.

Comment: @akrun oh come on it is different it its own way. I tend to complicate things due to lack of experience.

Comment: @akrun your solution also worked great! There's a lot for me to learn from in these two solutions.